# URL to upload an RDF file in Fuseki2

Tags: rdf, fuseki

Fuseki2 provides an HTTP service to upload file into a dataset - by default when creating a dataset in the admin web interface this is `/ds/upload`.

What is the exact protocol/parameters to use to upload an RDF/XML file at this URL ? concrete exemple welcome. Are there other URLs to upload an RDF file to Fuseki ?

I feel this should be documented [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-data-services.html) in principle, but the documentation page looks like a graph only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think whay you are looking for is the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol its use in Fuseki is documented here [SOH](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/soh.html)

HTH chris

Comment: SOH are command-line tools. I am looking for direct HTTP interaction with the Fuseki server. Probably my question could be : how to use the SPARQL graph store protocol with a Fuseki dataset ?

Comment: They're convenience scripts using the SPARQL graph store protocol. I thought either they'd provide the information you need or the w3c spec. linked to from that page would. Apologies if I've only confused the issue.

Comment: It makes sense actually. The URL I need is not /ds/upload but rather /ds/data on which the SPARQL Graph Store operations can be called. So doing a POST on .../ds/data?graph=http://www.mygraph.net, with Content-Type= application/rdf+xml worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If still actual, the answer is: 
1) endpoint `http://localhost:3030/somedataset/upload`
2) method POST `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`
3) in the `file` parameter, the actual file; for example, in the RDF/XML format

An example in Postman collection https://web.postman.co/collections/6292536-ee00ed87-66f0-4b4a-9054-816bbc01475e?version=latest&workspace=93430448-f758-4deb-8c8b-6c7a79d91a8e